# Cacti 0.8.8h - Poller[0] WARNING: Poller Output Table not Empty

Tags: cacti

Hopefully somebody will be able to assist me in troubleshooting.
I am trying to draw a CPU utilization graph for 2 Dell Powerconnect 8024F switches using a custom graph template that calls a Perl script.
The script works well when called from the command line, but graphs don't get created in Cacti.
The log message describing the problem is this:

**POLLER: Poller[0] WARNING: Poller Output Table not Empty. Issues Found: 6, Data Sources: (DS[134]), (DS[135]), (DS[136]), (DS[137]), (DS[138]), (DS[139])**

(BTW, RRD files don't get created; there has to be 6 of them - 3 for each of our 2 switches)
The problem does not happen with other graphs that do not utilize scripts.

The initial poller was Spine, later it was changed to cmd.php with no difference.
What I've tried is:
1) changed polling interval to 1 minute (in Cacti's GUI and in crontab);
2) manually created RRD files via Debug Data Source. Graphs appeared, but values were NaN, and RRD files never got updated.
3) manually truncated the table "poller_output". It got populated the next cycle.
4) changed the string in the Data Input Method from

```
perl <path_cacti>/scripts/62xx_cpu.pl -H <ip> -C <co> -version <ve> -port <port> -domain <do> -user <user> -pass <pass> -authprotocol <ap> -privatepassword <pp> -privateprotocol <ppo> -timeout <ti>
```

to

```
perl /usr/share/cacti/scripts/62xx_cpu.pl -H <ip>
```

and even to

```
/usr/bin/perl /var/lib/cacti/scripts/62xx_cpu.pl -H <ip>
```

(to eliminate implicit paths and links)

(I've added my community string directly in the script; the script returns values when called from the command line.)
5) changed PHP memory limit from 64M to 1024M;
6) changed the poller from Spine to cmd.

No luck so far.

Here's some info about my setup:

> Technical Support
>
> General Information Date  Mon, 12 Dec 2016 11:55:47 +0400 Cacti
>   Version   0.8.8h Cacti OS unix SNMP Version   NET-SNMP version: 5.7.2
>   RRDTool Version   RRDTool 1.4.x Hosts 3 Graphs    69 Data
>   Sources   Script/Command: 11 SNMP: 6 SNMP Query: 59 Total: 76
>
> Poller Information Interval   300 Type    cmd.php Items   Action[0]: 124
>   Action[1]: 11 Total: 135 Concurrent Processes 1 Max Threads   1 PHP
>   Servers   1 Script Timeout    25 Max OID  10 Last Run Statistics  Time:1.0357
>   Method:spine Processes:1 Threads:1 Hosts:4 HostsPerProcess:4
>   DataSources:131 RRDsProcessed:66
>
> PHP Information PHP Version   5.4.16 PHP OS   Linux PHP uname Linux
>   SRV-GILAN-LOG02 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC
>   2015 x86_64 PHP SNMP  Installed max_execution_time    30
>   memory_limit  1024M

Please advise - what I should try next?
Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.
Here's the link for the details:
http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=56659

Comment: What was the solution? Linking to another forum doesn't help people here.

Comment: The solution was to modify the Perl script, because its ending had no connection with the output fields expected by the associated graph template. This was rather strange, because both the script and the template were downloaded from the official Cacti site.